# How do I point to an array through an if loop

Tags: c

Ok, so I am trying to write a program where I bid on cars. What I'm trying to do is if the current bid is zero, then the minimum bid is the starting bid.  If the current bid is not zero, then the minimum bid is the current bid plus the minimum bid. I keep getting an error that says `incompatible types when assigning to type 'float[5]' from type 'float'`.

Here is my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int menu1();

    int main()
    {
        FILE * ifp = fopen("input2.txt","r"); //Open the input file
        int cars = 5, i , j, k; // Initialized cars and counters i, j, and k
        char *VIEW="VIEW", *BID="BID", *CLOSE="CLOSE", choice1[20]; //Initialize character arrays
        float CAR[5]={1,2,3,4,5},START_BID[5]={0.00}, MIN_BID[5]={0.00}, CUR_BID[5]={0.00}, USR_BID[5]={0.00}; //Initialized float arrays
        int compareLimit = 100, selection=0;

        //Scan the file and appropriate the numbers into their respective arrays
        for (i = 0; i < cars; i++)
            {
                fscanf(ifp, "%f %f", &START_BID[i],&MIN_BID[i]);
            }


        printf("Welcome to the Silent Auction\n\n");
        menu1(); //Display the menu


        while (selection < 3)
    {
            scanf("%s", choice1);

            int result = strncmp(choice1, VIEW, compareLimit); //Compare two strings
            if(result == 0)
            {
                selection = 1;

            }


            int result2 = strncmp(choice1, BID, compareLimit); //Compare two strings
            if(result2 == 0)
            {
                selection = 2;

            }

            int result3 = strncmp(choice1, CLOSE, compareLimit); //Compare two strings
            if(result3 == 0)
            {
                selection = 3;
            }

            if (selection == 1)
            {
                printf("Number\tCurrent Bid\tMinimum Increase\n");
                printf("1\t$%.2f\t\t$%.2f\n",CUR_BID[0], MIN_BID[0]);
                printf("2\t$%.2f\t\t$%.2f\n",CUR_BID[1], MIN_BID[1]);
                printf("3\t$%.2f\t\t$%.2f\n",CUR_BID[2], MIN_BID[2]);
                printf("4\t$%.2f\t\t$%.2f\n",CUR_BID[3], MIN_BID[3]);
                printf("5\t$%.2f\t\t$%.2f\n",CUR_BID[4], MIN_BID[4]);

                menu1();
            }


            else if (selection == 2)
            {
                int k;
                float usr_bid;

                printf("Which auction would you like to bid on? (1-5)\n");
                scanf("%d", &k);

                if (CUR_BID[k-1] != 0.00)
                    MIN_BID = CUR_BID[k-1] + MIN_BID[k-1];
                else
                    printf("The minimum bid is %.2f\n", MIN_BID[k - 1]);

                printf("How much would you like to bid?\n");
                scanf("%f", &usr_bid);
                if (usr_bid < MIN_BID[k-1])
                    printf("Sorry, that bid is not high enough.\n");
                else
                    CUR_BID[k-1] = usr_bid + CUR_BID[k-1];

                menu1();
            }

            else
            {
                int i;

                for (i=0; i<cars; i++)
                    if (CUR_BID!=0)
                        printf("Auction %d sold for $%f\n", CAR[i],CUR_BID[i]);
                    else
                        printf("Auction %d did not sell.\n");

                break;
            }
    }

            fclose(ifp);

        return 0;
    }


    int menu1()
    {
    printf("Please make a selection (In all caps):\n");
        printf("\tView Auctions [VIEW]\n");
        printf("\tBid on an Auction [BID]\n");
        printf("\tClose Auctions [CLOSE]\n");
    }
```

What my code is doing in the `else if (selection == 2)` section is it asks which bid I want to bid on. Then whatever number I choose from 1-5 is in int k. Then it checks the current bid for that selection so it looks in the `CUR_BID[k-1]` array where if the number is 3, then it checks in the 2nd spot in the array. I am getting the error from:

```
    MIN_BID = CUR_BID[k-1] + MIN_BID[k-1];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't assign to arrays, let alone assign a float to a float array. Either make it a float or choose an element of it to assign to.

Comment: "Any ideas?" -- You mean aside from the extraordinarily obvious? I mean, heck, the compiler even spelled it out for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MIN_BID` is an array of floats, yet you're trying to assign just a single `float` to it.  It looks like what you want is `MIN_BID[k-1] = CUR_BID[k-1] + MIN_BID[k-1];`.

Answer (score 0):

`MIN_BID` has array type. You'll have to pick a slot.

```
MIN_BID[0] = ...
```